# Animated series in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

hi I want to create a highchart like this [image: map demo]

I have created a dotted line highchart, but don't know how to put this animation.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({


        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            color: '#FF0000',
           dashStyle: 'dash'
        }]
    });
});
```

My fiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/puuqbo6n/

Comment: fiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/puuqbo6n/

Comment: you want chart running like this??

Comment: yes i want the same animation

Comment: This is not something highcharts does out of the box. It is intriguing, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS animation can accomplish this by setting the `stroke-dashoffset` in the @keyframes `to` to some negative value (assuming you want it to go left-to-right) and running the animation on infinite (assuming you want that too).  Technique mostly [learned here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/).

```
.highcharts-series path {
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/puuqbo6n/3/

However, while working on this, my CPU usage seemed to go up.